# connect to sharepoint REST API with username and password

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I don't have any experience with Sharepoint. I need to download a file from a Sharepoint server in Python. I have a couple of different URLs that supposedly both point to the same file on Sharepoint:

```
https://connect.[our-partner].com/sites/ftp/[i think an FTP site name]/[path-to-file]

and

https://connect.[our-partner].com/sites/ftp/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/ftp/[i think an FTP site name]/[path-to-file]')
```

My #1 preference would be to download it via REST. If I can't do that, I guess FTP would be OK.

I only have a username and password. Am I correct to understand that it will never work for me and that I need to get some other sort of credentials?

The only other option is logging in w/ Selenium and downloading it, which I am really trying to avoid.

Comment: I think you’ll have to do an oauth2 flow

Comment: Can I get the client_id/secret for Oauth2 from the username/password, or do I need to get the administrator to grant them for me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to register a sharepoint app only and request an accesstoken to use rest. Please refer to the steps in following article

https://anoopt.medium.com/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf